# C++: Public member of a private nested class type

Tags: c++, inner-classes, class-visibility

I have the following code:

```
class Base
{
  private:
    class NestedBase
    {
      public:
        void Do() {}
    };

  public:
    NestedBase nested;
};

int main()
{
  Base b;
  b.nested.Do(); // line A compiles
  Base::NestedBase instance; // line B doesn't compile
}
```

`NestedBase` class is a private nested class of `Base`, so it seems natural  that line B doesn't compile. But, on the other hand, variable `b` has the public member `nested`, and I can call its method `Do()` from outside of `Base` (as in line A). What are the precise rules that regulate access to the private nested class (or its members) in such case? What does the standard say on this?

Answer (score 6):

According to the standard, [$11.7/1 Nested classes [class.access.nest]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access.nest#1):

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member.

So, it's quite simple. `NestedBase` is a `private` member of class `Base`, so `Base::NestedBase` can't be accessed in `main()`.

`b.nested.Do();` is fine because `nested` and `Do()` are both `public` members. The fact that `NestedBase` is a `private` nested class of `Base` doesn't matter, it's irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Type name `NestedBase` is a private member of the class.

```
class Base
{
private:
    class NestedBase
    {
    public:
        void Do() {}
    };
    //...
```

So you can not explicitly access it outside the class where the name is declared.

But you can access the name implicitly the following way:)

```
decltype( Base::nested) instance;
```

Comment: I think `Base::nested` must be _public_ member of `Base`. @Vlad, did you mean this?